# Open password protected file

Tags: excel, vba

I want to check if file is password protected. The below code is working fine. But I workbook is password protected, please advise as to where to put the password in below code

```
Sub Example1()

    If GetAttr("c:\test.xls") And vbReadOnly Then
        MsgBox "File is Read-only"
    Else
        MsgBox "File is not read-only"
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want to open the file as subject of your post mentions.
To open the file as per VBA Help

```
expression.Open(FileName, UpdateLinks, ReadOnly, Format, Password, WriteResPassword, IgnoreReadOnlyRecommended, Origin, Delimiter, Editable, Notify, Converter, AddToMru, Local, CorruptLoad)
```

Hence, usage:

```
Workbooks.Open Filename:= "C:\Documents and Settings\My Documents\Book2.xls", Password:="YourPasswordHere"
```

Answer (score 0):

To determine if a workseet or a workbook is protected

```
Option Explicit

Public Function isSheetProtected(Optional ByRef ws As Worksheet = Nothing) As Boolean

    If ws Is Nothing Then Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet

    isWorksheetProtected = ws.ProtectContents Or _
                           ws.ProtectDrawingObjects Or _
                           ws.ProtectScenarios

End Function
```

---

```
Public Function isFileProtected(Optional ByRef wb As Workbook = Nothing) As Boolean

    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook

    isWorkbookProtected = ws.ProtectWindows Or ws.ProtectStructure

End Function
```

---

To un-protect a workbook:

```
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Public Sub unprotectFile(Optional ByRef wb As Worksheet = Nothing)

    If wb Is Nothing Then Set wb = Application.ActiveWorkbook

    If isFileProtected(wb) Then wb.Unprotect Password:="YourPassword"

End Sub

'------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```